# How to merge data based on first column?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have some simple data:

```
digital 5434
ero 3464
3es 69955
digital 1948
ero 5783
ride 5884
```

I want to process this input file and sum all 2nd field values where the first field is the same. My final output file should look like this:

```
digital 7382
ero 9247
3es 69955
ride 5884
```

I think this can be done with awk?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what you need to do. It _looks_ like you want to make the second field be the sum of all values with the same first field. Is that what you need?

Comment: Oh yes, this is what i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple approach:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}' data 
ero 9247
3es 69955
digital 7382
ride 5884
```

Note that this will store most of the data in your file in memory so it could cause problems for very large files.